# Why does my Ubuntu Server hang on shutdown?

Tags: server, shutdown, systemd

Why does my Ubuntu Server hang on shutdown?

My Ubuntu 16.04.1 Server, hangs on shutdown, it unmounts all the mount points and then just hangs. It never cuts the power, just keeps doing those messages at the bottom

```
INFO: task systemd-shutdow:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Tainted: P           OE   4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

Do I need to echo 0 in to that file?

I'm guessing I can't get any logs from `/var/logs` because that would of been unmounted.

[image: photo of screen with shutdown messages]

[image: photo of screen with repeated "blocked" message]